# ansible-pull on remote hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-pull

I want run the playbook on remote host, which the playbook is in github. So, I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/splunkuserdeveloperadministrator/using-ansible-pull-in-ansible-projects-ac04466643e8) and forked the repo https://github.com/vincesesto/ansible-pull-example

In side the repo, I have modified `hosts` file to my server IP. When run `ansible-pull`

```
veeru@carb0n:~/ansible-example$ ansible-pull -U https://github.com/veerendra2/ansible-pull-example -i hosts
Starting Ansible Pull at 2019-06-26 16:26:30
/usr/local/bin/ansible-pull -U https://github.com/veerendra2/ansible-pull-example -i hosts
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: carb0n
ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

Not sure why it is picking current server name `carb0n` even I specified `-i hosts` argument.

here is my `hosts` file

```
[hydrogen]
10.250.30.11
```

local.yml

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: install example application
    copy:
      src: ansible_test_app
      dest: /tmp/
      owner: root
      group: root
```

I had changed `local.yml` to `hydrogen.yml`, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure why it is picking current server name carb0n even I specified -i hosts argument.

Sure, because ansible **pull** is designed to run against the **current host**, always. If you want to run against a *remote* server then you are supposed to use `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` and then your specification of a host list and the connection mechanism would start to make sense again.

Using `ansible-pull` is designed for the cases where it is either impossible, or highly undesirable for something to connect to the managed host. That can be due to firewall, security policies, or any number of reasons. But policies are usually less strict about what a managed host can, itself, connect to, and that's why pulling configuration *onto* the host can be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why is there option for inventory `-i`?

Comment: I actually didn't know there was one until I saw you try to use it, but my guess would be so you can use existing dynamic inventory mechanisms to declare host facts, since the inventory does several things: groups hosts, defines connectivity mechanisms, declares per-host facts, and likely other stuff; there are for sure non-inventory mechanisms for doing all of those things, but I guess ansible wants to be flexible, even at the risk of confusing combinations like you stumbled upon